# GCM Demo Application's failure to register to tomcat server when tested on real Device

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I have Implemented GcmDemo Application,it is working fine when tested with Emulator

But the same application not working when tested with a real Device

i'm able to register with GCM Server and Getting Reg ID,But not able to register with TomCat Server

I have followed the tutorial http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/

LogCat:

```
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424): Failed to register on attempt 1
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.1.2.101 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:848)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
06-19 12:44:27.620: E/trade(4424
```

Could any one Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check availability of your PC(with tomcat server) from your device browser. Just type 192.1.2.101:8080 in url field. It should show you default tomcat welcome page. If it does not,  find your PC(server) ip address in local network. Your problem is that your device cannot find ip address in your network.

Answer (score 1):

You were able to run in emulator because both Client(Emulator) and Server were in same network.
Now you are trying on Device, you are getting connection time out because Client(Device) is not able to locate the local Server. Connect your DEvice to the same Network as your Server.

To make sure that Server is accessible from Device, you can browse your server IP in Web Browser of your device.

Comment: I have typed the Server URL on my Device Browser,I'm not able to open Tomcat Home Page,The Ip address of my System i have not down by command IPConfig

Comment: is your device is in the same network as your system? To open Server page on Device ,your device and Server need to be in same network